# FirebaseException: Not able to query a collectionGroup

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to do a pretty simple query in firebase for a **collectionGroup**. I only want to get all the products that are of the type "Restuarant". The code is below:

```
QuerySnapshot res = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('products')
    .where("type", isEqualTo: "Restuarant")
    .get();
```

It keeps throwing a FirebaseException as below:

[image]

I have added an exception in the Firebase indexes. It is a single field index. [image: firebase index]

[image: firebase Collection]

What is the issue here? Why is this Exception occurring?

Comment: Check out this link, also make sure you have it indexed in firebase. The link is for Javascript, but it's the same concept.
https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad I followed this link's tutorial to add the index that I already have.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the index to show that it is a collection *group* index? For example, here is one of mine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkVDV.png

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In the image you have attached, you have a composite index, right? I followed this link to add a single field index. Do you think I need a composite index? https://firebase.blog/posts/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries

Comment: You don't need a composite index, but you *do* need a collection group index - which are not auto-added.

Comment: How can I add one? Can you please guide me to a tutorial or anything?

Comment: Are you using the security rules as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#collection_group_queries_and_security_rules). Can you provide the security rules you are using?

Comment: I'm using simple security rule that allows read and write to all authenticated users. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwSTV.png

Comment: Though it is not recommended in production, just to test, can you try with `allow read, write: if true;` in place of `allow read, write: if request.auth!=null;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to get it working by adding a composite index. After adding the composite index, I was able to perform orderBy query too, using the rating field.

```
QuerySnapshot res = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('products')
    .where("type", isEqualTo: "Restuarant")
    .orderBy("rating", descending: true)
    .get();
```

[image]